# Definition of formal neighbourhood

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider the scheme $\mathbb{P}^1$, and the point $0 \in \mathbb{P}^1$. What is the formal neighbourhood of $0$ in $\mathbb{P}^1$?

Or if you know a good reference, that would be helpful.

Comment: My first guess would be that for a ring $R$, the formal neighborhood of $0$ in $\Bbb{P}^1_R$ is $R[[X]]$, the ring of [formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series) in the variable $X$ with coefficients in $R$. Does that make any sense in your context?

Comment: One reference for a general exposition is Hartshorne II.9.

Comment: @NilsMatthes I would probably say it is $Spf (R[[X]])$ rather than the ring itself.

Comment: pg 190 of Hartshorne (II.9) seems helpful.

Answer (score 8):

The formal neighbourhood of a closed subscheme $X$ of $Y$ refers to the formal scheme obtained by completing $Y$ along $X$; see the discussion of formal schemes in Hartshorne for (unfortunately not that many) more details.

This is certainly *not* an open subscheme of $Y$; indeed, as Marci notes, the underlying topological space is simply $X$ itself. However, the ringed space structure has been "thickened up" to incorporate the normal diretions to $X$ in $Y$.

One thing you could look at is a paper of Beauville and Laszlo where they explain how to make certain constructions, e.g. bundles, by gluing data on the formal n.h. of $X$ to data on the complement of $X$.  (A discussion of this paper and of related earlier work can be found in the comments [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/61942/2874) and also in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/112652/2874).)

Answer (score 0):

One thing to add. If you are interested in the formal neighborhood F of X in Y, then the underlying topological space of the formal neighborhood is X.